My executable python file packaged via pyinstaller works on my machine but not others
I have a py file which I packaged as an executable via pyinstaller. The exe works just fine on my machine as an exe, but it will not run on my colleague's. Both PCs are on Windows 11.
The following libraries are utilized:
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import win32com.client
from xlwings.utils import rgb_to_int
from xlwings.constants import LookAt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from pandasql import sqldf
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib
import pyodbc

The py script is over 400 lines and connects to two SQL tables which the user has entitlements for and two Excel files on a shared drive. The Excel file paths are hardcoded in the script.
I had to use hidden imports to find pyslite2, MySQLdb, and psycopg2. I used onefile in pyinstaller.The pyinstaller log is shown below.
PS C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Scripts> .\pyinstaller --hidden-import pysqlite2 --hidden-import MySQLdb --hidden-import psycopg2 -F 'Script.py'
554 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.8.0, contrib hooks: 2024.7
554 INFO: Python: 3.12.2
586 INFO: Platform: Windows-11-10.0.22621-SP0
601 INFO: Python environment: C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv
601 INFO: wrote C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Scripts\Script.spec
617 INFO: Module search paths (PYTHONPATH):
['C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe',
'C:\Program Files\Python312\python312.zip',
'C:\Program Files\Python312\DLLs',
'C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib',
'C:\Program Files\Python312',
'C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv',
'C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32',
'C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
'C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
'C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Scripts']
1092 INFO: checking Analysis
1214 INFO: checking PYZ
1328 INFO: checking PKG
1328 INFO: Building because toc changed
1328 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Script.pkg
19102 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Script.pkg completed successfully.
19102 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\run.exe
19102 INFO: checking EXE
19117 INFO: Building because name changed
19117 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
19133 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Scripts\dist\Script.exe
19288 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
19356 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
19356 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
19438 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
19482 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
27485 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
PS C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject.venv\Scripts>

Could you please share some logs from your friends computer? Optimal way would be to start a batch shell and execute executable from there to see if any exceptions occur they should be logged. First guess would be that some dependencies are missing and on your pc they are loaded from global python installation or anything that is specific to your pc was left in code, like hardcoded absolute paths. Could you please also share any of the code you are complaining about? With this question you are not giving us much to work with.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Thanks. The script is over 400 lines long. I have updated the question with a bit more detail including the pyinstaller log. How would I go about directing my colleague to run the executable from a batch shell and to then send me exceptions?
